# What is Hypercorrection?

Tags: hypercorrection

I was assigned a presentation on Hypercorrection yet I have absolutely no idea what it is (the definitions I found were really vague).  Please help me grasp the basis of it and kindly provide some examples/cases. Thank you so so much!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on the Linguistics SE; this isn't English-specific.

Comment: And I've voted to re-open it because it most likely is about English.

Comment: Contributor herisson gives a good working definition of _hypercorrection_ at [Is there a difference between hypercorrection, overregularization, and overcompensation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202623/is-there-a-difference-between-hypercorrection-overregularization-and-overcompe). There's even a hypercorrection tag on ELU.

Comment: But this question does require you mention what you have found and why it wasn't sufficient for making you grasp its meaning. There is [an article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection) that seems clear enough.

Comment: The question has already been asked: [Is there a difference between hypercorrection, overregularization, and overcompensation? If so, how?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202623/is-there-a-difference-between-hypercorrection-overregularization-and-overcompe)

Answer (score 1):

Hypercorrection is applying a rule to a case for which the rule is not intended. It is best demonstrated with examples:

- Because ‘jalapeño’ has a tilde, many people write and say ‘habañero peppers’ even though habanero doesn’t have a tilde.
- Some people who have heard that “me and my friend” should be “my friend and I” will say things like “I planned a trip for my friend and I” which is incorrect because ‘I’ is used only for the subject and never the object.
- ‘Octopus’ is often pluralized as ‘octopi’ based on the idea that Latin words ending in -us are pluralized by changing the ending to -i, but ‘octopus’ is derived from Greek and is properly pluralized as ‘octopuses’.

Comment: Your third example illustrates the etymological fallacy. Though some argue that the Latinate plural was wrongly formulated, usage has now certainly made it acceptable. There are those who say that, coming from Greek, 'octopodes' should be the accepted plural form rather than the anglicised version, but again usage drives the language and they are in a tiny  ...

Comment: minority. In any case, _while octopus may ultimately come from Greek it had a stay in New Latin before arriving here_ [[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/the-many-plurals-of-octopus-octopi-octopuses-octopodes)]. Both 'octopuses' and 'octopi' are licensed by say [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/octopus), [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/octopus) and [RHK Webster's](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/octopus).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth We mustn't forget that "octopodes" is just more fun to say.

Comment: Fair enough points, but even if ‘octopi’ has wriggled into acceptable usage, the idea still demonstrates the concept of hypercorrection.

Comment: Not if the word entered, as many claim, via New Latin rather than Greek.

Comment: It would be more helpful and relevant if you give other examples of hypercorrection